# Error receiving broadcast Intent (has extras)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager, android-pendingintent

I am new to android. I am trying to add proximity alert for different locations that are retrieved from mysql database.I retrive locations and store them to an arrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> latArray, lngArray;
```

Now, I'm adding proximity alert to the locations like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < latArray.size(); i++) {     
                setProximityAlert(Double.valueOf(latArray.get(i)),Double.valueOf(lngArray.get(i)));
        }

private void setProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntentToFire);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius,expiration, proximityIntent);

        // register the broadcast receiver to start listening for proximity alerts
        filter = new IntentFilter(IntentToFire);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    }
```

Now my broadcast receiver class is as follows:

```
  public class MyProximityAlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING; //indicates whether proximity alert is entering or exiting


        //Retrieve extended data from the intent and return false if no value of the desired type is stored with the 

given name.
                Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

                 if (entering) {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
                        System.out.print("entering");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
                        System.out.print("exiting");
                    }

                 NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        //Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new activity
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);        

                        //create icons and other stuffs for notification
                        Notification notification = createNotification();
                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, 
                            "Proximity Alert!", "In the area.", pendingIntent);

                        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

                    }
........
}
```

As soon as I receive notification I get the following error:
Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.app (has extras) }

On double clicking few lines of error code, it takes me to the line:

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

I am also unregistering and re-registering receiver on pause and on restart:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
        super.onRestart();
    }
```

I don't understand what I amd doing wrong? Am I doing something wrong when adding proximity alert? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you post more about the exception that is being thrown, please?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215